# gwt - How can I change EntryPoint in GWT?

Tags: gwt, entry-point

Basically I have implemented a Editor (let's say `Editor_A`) entry point. Everything works fine in gwt.

Then I implemented another entry point `Editor_B` with different widget layout. Now, I want to disable the entry point Editor_A, and let Editor_B up.

I modified the following things:

**in Editor.html**

I changed `<script language="javascript" src="com.mycompany.Editor_A/com.mycompany.Editor_A.nocache.js"></script>` to `<script language="javascript" src="com.mycompany.Editor_B/com.mycompany.Editor_B.nocache.js"></script>`

**in Editor.gwt.xml**

I changed `<entry-point class="com.mycompany.Editor_A"/>` to `<entry-point class="com.mycompany.Editor_B"/>`

However, I don't think the above changes are correct. Editor_A is gone, but Editor_B is not up and there is nothing in the web page.

Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have to change the path of the bootstrap script (*.nocache.js) if you just want to change the entry point. Changing the entry-point class in Editor.gwt.xml should be enough.

Unless you specified the "rename-to" attribute in Editor.gwt.xml, the bootstrap script path should match the fully qualified name of your GWT module (i.e. the full path of Editor.gwt.xml but without the trailing ".gwt.xml"). Base on the info you provided I think it should be:

```
<script language="javascript" src="com.mycompany.Editor/com.mycompany.Editor.nocache.js"></script>
```